# Need to prevent popup getting closed on press of esc key

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a popup inside which i have selectonechoice drop down.
While clicking on the drop down and pressing escape key entire popup is getting closed in ADF.
My requirement is to prevent closing popup on press of esc key if the selectonechoice is selected.

I have been trying to close normal popup by using below code which is not working

```
window.onkeydown = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 27){
        event.cancel();  
    }
}
```

i have also tried out options to overwrite clientlisteners
popupClosed and popupCanceled which didn't help either.

Any help on how to interpret the esc key functionality and prevent ADF popup getting closed.

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault();`?

Answer (score 0):

Each ADF Faces component class has a javascript equivalent. For popup RichPopup class is reflected as ADFRichPopup in javascript.

You can achieve that by supressing cancel's method in javascript object ADFRichPopup:

```
<af:resource type="javascript">
  function onPopupOpened(event)   {  
              var popup = event.getSource();
              popup.cancel = function() {}; 
  } 
</af:resource>



<af:popup>
 <af:clientListener method="onPopupOpened" type="popupOpened"/>
</af:popup>
```

Of course, this means you won't be able to use cancel() method yourself, but you can use hide() method instead.

Comment: As event.getSource() didn't give me ADFRichPopup if the focus is on any of the child elements of the popup. I have used `var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent("popupId"); stdPopup.cancel = function() {};` .  But it didn't prevent closing popup on pressing Esc Key.

Comment: event.getSource()  will give you popup instance 100%, if you place the client listener inside the popup tag. If is not, it just means there is something wrong with your code. This solution was checked with Oracle support, it works for sure.